# Where should I put states in my React App

Tags: reactjs

I have a Form with 3 states. should I put those states in `App.js` ? because I'm using separate and custom component for my router called `Router.js`.
this is my `App.js` and as you can see I don't have any Form component because it is on `Home.js`.
if I put my states to `App.js` How can I pass them to child component?

so `Router.js` for states or `App.js`?

`App.js`

```
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./views/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Router from "./routes/Router";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />
      <Router />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Router.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../views/pages/Home";
import Login from "../views/pages/Login";
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

Comment: seems you don't want to use redux so you can user useContext hook

Comment: @ShahVipul in `Router.js` ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext || 
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/

Answer (score 3):

[image]If you want to just use that data you can use Context

- Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language

But if you want to change data everywhere it's better to use state managers like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

```js
function App() {
const [mainState,setMainstate]=useState({baseline:{},navbar:{},router:{home:{}}});
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <CssBaseline state={mainState} setState={setMainstate}/>
      <Navbar state={mainState} setState={setMainstate} />
      <Router state={mainState} setState={setMainstate} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

for instance in `<Router/>`

```js
const Router = ({state,setState}) => {
const sampleChangeState=()=>{
setState({...state,router:{...state.router,home:{color:red}}})
}
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home state={state.router.home}
setState={setState}
 />} />
      <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/Login" element={<Login state={state.router.login} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: I want to change them as well but for a simple login form example, redux is kind of overkill, isn't it ?

Comment: the project is not real. I'm using it for practice.

Comment: so, you can put all-state in-app and pass chang evet as props for children

Comment: but how? I can pass as a prop in Router.js but since there is no component rendered in App.js I don't exactly know how to do it

Comment: pass to `<Navbar />` and router pass to elements

Comment: Because of these complexities, state management emerged

Comment: I made an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle **separated states for the components**.

- Login should manage all related to login.
- Home should manage all related to the form that you mention.

You can have a callback from login to Router if you want to redirect the user after successful auth.

Comment: If you want to practice the "show" and "hide" sections depending if the user is logged, you can check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71348477/3285083

Comment: it is more complex. I have sign up and login form. 2 page react app. I want to save sign up data in local storage and then make user being able to sing in. but I don't know where should I put those states. I don't think separate states could be possible since they are connected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

**Passing states from app.js to home component(as props).**

```
import React from "react"
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./views/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Router from "./routes/Router";
function App() {
  const [formStates,setFormStates] = React.useState({
       stateOne : "",
       stateTwo : "",
       stateThree : "",
   });
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />
      <Router formStates={formStates} setFormStates={setFormStates}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And In the `Router.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../views/pages/Home";
import Login from "../views/pages/Login";
const Router = ({formStates,setFormStates}) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/Home" element={<Home formStates={formStates}  setFormStates= 
        {setFormStates} />} />
      <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

Comment: why we shouldn't directly define states in Router and passing them to the Home?